# Microsoft Cognitive Speech to Text - detect language

Tags: speech-recognition, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using the Microsoft Cognitive Speech to Text API, and my question is
How to detect the language of the audio being analyzed? Is this possible?

Comment: Is there any STT service that doesn't need to know the language in advance? I have samples of all the STT services but I can't find one that auto-detects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. Not even Google Cloud supports it ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44129195/1623249)).